# Non linear optimization of a matrix through rotation

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to find the best rotation matrix $R \in O_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ (rotation matrix, with respect to the euclidian norm 2), such as:
$$U = R V$$
In that case, $U$ is the fixed value. I am hoping to find the $R$ and $V$ such as $\lVert V \rVert_{1/3}$ is minimum ($\lVert . \rVert_{1/3}$ being the entrywise norm). So, the objective is to minimize:
$$\operatorname{argmin}_{R \in O_{n}(\mathbb{R})} (\lVert V \rVert_{1/3}) $$

How could that be done? An iterative process would be fine. Note, I spoke about the $\lVert . \rVert_{1/3}$ norm, but any norm with $\lVert . \rVert_{1/p}$ with $p \geq 3$ would suit me.

Comment: Use `\operatorname{x}` to render `x` as a supported function: `\operatorname{argmin}` renders as $\operatorname{argmin}$

Comment: Erm... Aren't all Schatten norms invariant under rotations? Or you mean something other than sum of the singular values to the corresponding power?

Comment: @fedja I think you are right. I got confused with the naming on the Wikipedia page. I was thinking about the entrywise norm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#%22Entrywise%22_matrix_norms.

Comment: It is ugly: there are plenty of local minima and there seems to be no way to create some criterion that would tell you that you have reached the global minimum even you are there. How large is the value of $n$ you are interested in?

Comment: Sure thing. The value of $n$ would depend on the problem, but it is around 10.

Comment: There are a lot of local minima. At least $n!$, since either permutation of lines for the $R$ matrix would work. But those are all valid solutions for my problem. The idea is mainly to find a rotation matrix that would minimize the line correlation of $V$. (That is the idea anyway).

Comment: I meant that there is a lot of *non-equivalent* (to the global one and to each other) local minima. Your line correlation remark is interesting. What exactly do you mean by that? It may be more tractable than your fractional norm problem.

Comment: Sure thing! The idea behind this goal is to have the $V$ matrix as scarse as possible. I won't be able to find a rotation that maximize the number of zeros in the matrix, but I want to find a rotation that force to have as much values close to zeroes as possible. With that real life problem, I know that it would lead to the line by line cosine correlation to be as low as possible, which what I aim for.

Comment: I am curious though. I can't visualize the intuition that you have with the number of local minima. I can see one by permutation of lines, but what else? And why, if I may ask?

Comment: "line by line cosine correlation" Erm... Aren't the angles between the lines (columns) also rotation invariant under left multiplication, or you again mean something else (say, rows)? Also, once you get all pairwise angles (or cosines), how do you combine them into the objective function?

Comment: Just think of $n=2$. Every time you hit $0$ in one entry you have a cusp and the rest is smooth, so you have a local minimum plus you can get a smooth one too.

Comment: You are right. When I was saying "line", I was meaning row. Combining them in one objective function is hard, so that is why I was trying to translate the objective in a matrix norm. If I would have to combine them in one objective, I would try to minimize the maximum (infinite norm) of cosine similarities.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128723/discussion-between-emile-d-and-fedja).